# ActiveMQ Modified Broker

Tags: message, activemq-classic, broker

I wanto to write a modified ActiveMQ broker that when he listens to **producers'** messages of a specific topic to handle them alternatively (use HDFS API for example and not use default persisten store). Do you have any ideas where to start with?

thanks in advance, 
Petrucci

Answer (score 1):

You could either implement your own ActiveMQ [message store](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.3.1/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/store/package-summary.html) for HDFS which would allow ActiveMQ to use HDFS as a persistence store, or you could create an ActiveMQ [broker plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html) which would allow you to intercept messages as they enter the broker. Both are very different approaches, so it really depends on your requirements as to which path to take.

Bruce

Comment: as i can see the broker plugin approch is easier , isn't it? and using this broker plugin means that i should build activemq for scratch, am i right?

Comment: There's no need to build ActiveMQ from scratch. You just need the appropriate ActiveMQ JARs in your classpath to utilize the correct classes.